# How to insert image project outside subdomain directory, and also how to retrieved project outside images

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, laravel-8, image-upload

Laravel 8 version project is main domain with another have a subdomain project crated by raw PHP, both projects are using one database. My need subdomain Raw PHP folder inserted image retrieved in Laravel project and Laravel project inserted image path will be subdomain folder

Try to retrieve image in laravel project from subdomain project

```
{{asset('./../../sub-domain/folder/subfor/'.$user->image)}}
```

Comment: That will not work. The lowest directory you can go is the `public` directory of Laravel. That image on the subdomain has to be retrieved in another way